# Expectation value quantum mechanics momentum operator

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, expected-value

What is the random variable that belongs to the expectation value of momentum in quantum mechanics?

Or in general: Is there any way we can define the expectation values that occur in quantum mechanics via the definition of expectation values by using random variables?

Or more precisely: What are the random variables in quantum mechanics?

For people who are interested in getting some background on what I am asking:

1. [Expected Values of Operators in Quantum Mechanics](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/540275/expected-values-of-operators-in-quantum-mechanics)
2. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation_value_%28quantum_mechanics%29#Example_in_configuration_space

Comment: You get not only the expectation value but the whole probability distribution of any measurable from the wave function, what more are you asking for?

Comment: What is the randomn variable that belongs to 'let's say: the expectation value of the momentum?'

Comment: The measured momentum

Comment: could you write down the actual map please?

Comment: You set up your experiment, then you rpess a button to perform experiment, a computer probably records the momentum and you read off the screen?

Comment: that is not what i am asking for

Comment: Yes it is, unless you mean something else then what you wrote.

Comment: @Andrews Thanks for your [edit]s.  Please use leading `1.`, `2.`, etc, for [numbered `<ol>` lists](//math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting), and MathJax `$1$` for math expressions/tables.  More importantly, please write [semantically correct Markdown and MathJax code](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/164993) for forward compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the link you posted from another question explain, in the position representation $\psi(x)$, the eigenvectors with eigenvalues $\hbar k$ of the momentum operator $\hat{p}=\frac{\hbar}{i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ are functions of the form $\psi_k(x)=e^{ikx}$. If we want the probability distribution for the measurement of some observable $O$ in a given state, we need to perform the spectral decomposition $O=\int k dP_k$, where $P_k(\cdot)=\psi_k(\psi_k,\cdot)$ is the projector in the eingespace of eigenvalue $k$ (I assumed that the eigenvalue is non-degenerate for simplicity, but the same also holds for the general case). Then the probability distribution will be given by $p(k)=(\psi, P_k \psi)$. So, for the case of the momentum operator, we have the probability distribution
$$p(k)=(\psi,\psi_k)(\psi_k,\psi)=|(\psi_k,\psi)|^2=\left|\int e^{-ikx}\psi(x)dx\right|^2=|\tilde{\psi}(k)|^2,$$
where $\tilde{\psi}(k)$ is the Fourier transform of $\psi(x)$.